# 5 second delay on ldap_bind() to Active Directory

Tags: php, codeigniter, ldap, adldap

I have a strange problem on a production server running Debian squeeze with Apache 2.2.16 and PHP 5.3.3-7 and Suhosin. On my development machine, Windows 7 64bit running XAMPP, I don't have the same problem.

The problem is: I am using the adLDAP PHP API to access a Windows Active Directory Domain Controller, and on the *production* box, there is a 5 second delay *sometimes* calling **ldap_bind()**. I don't get this on the development box - and they are accessing the same LDAP server with the same details and credentials.

ldap_connect() executes fine, but it's ldap_bind() that is giving me the error. I have confirmed this through logging with CodeIgniter.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further see what's going on you can enable debug output of the ldap module:

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
```

5s is typically a timeout against the server. And when you say it only happens sometimes, and only on production, suggest that the problem is in your network rather than in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the debugging option would be very useful in diagnosing it. Strangely, I believe the issue was DNS related, despite both dev and prod environments using the same DNS server. I solved it by simply changing the LDAP server being called in ldap_connect() to the IP address rather than the FQDN. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. It appears to have been a DNS problem for me too. I pinged the server twice and got two different IP addresses. One timed out, the other didn't. I used the good IP address in the ldap_connect rather than the name and the problem is gone.